# MassTransit C# - RoutingKey works in program.cs setup but not inside a ConsumerDefinition

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I've been trying to move my Consumer set up to a ConsumerDefinition to try and modularise my Consumer project. I have a problem where the program.cs set up version works perfectly, however in the ConsumerDefinition setup, the routing key seems to get ignored and I can publish a message with almost any routing key and it'll match.

The following code only accepts the REGISTER event as I want.

Program.cs

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                {
                    x.AddConsumer<RegisteredUserConsumer>();

                    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                    {
                        cfg.Host(
                            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOST"),
                            "host",
                            hostConfig =>
                        {
                            hostConfig.Username(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME"));
                            hostConfig.Password(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PASSWORD"));
                        });
                        
                        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(e =>
                        {
                            e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
                            e.ClearSerialization();
                            e.UseRawJsonSerializer();
                            
                            if (e is IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator rabbit) 
                            {
                                rabbit.Bind("amq.topic", ex =>
                                {
                                    ex.ExchangeType = "topic";
                                    ex.RoutingKey = $"KK.EVENT.CLIENT.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENTID")}.SUCCESS.#.REGISTER";
                                });
                            }
                        
                            e.ConfigureConsumer<RegisteredUserConsumer>(context);
                        });
                    });
                });
```

However, the following code accepts multiple routing keys

Program.cs

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                {
                    x.AddConsumer<RegisteredUserConsumer, RegisteredUserConsumerDefinition>();

                    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                    {
                        cfg.Host(
                            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOST"),
                            "host",
                            hostConfig =>
                        {
                            hostConfig.Username(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME"));
                            hostConfig.Password(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PASSWORD"));
                        });
                        
                        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                    });
                });
```

ConsumerDefinition

```
public class RegisteredUserConsumerDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<RegisteredUserConsumer>
{
    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(
        IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
        IConsumerConfigurator<RegisteredUserConsumer> consumerConfigurator,
        IRegistrationContext context)
    {
        endpointConfigurator.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
        endpointConfigurator.ClearSerialization();
        endpointConfigurator.UseRawJsonSerializer();

        if (endpointConfigurator is IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator rabbit) 
        {
            rabbit.Bind("amq.topic", ex =>
            {
                ex.ExchangeType = "topic";
                ex.RoutingKey = $"KK.EVENT.CLIENT.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENTID")}.SUCCESS.#.REGISTER";
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When testing using the management interface in RabbitMQ, If I use the routing key `h`, or `KK.Something`, it does not match. However, the following keys do work

```
KK.EVENT.CLIENT.00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000.SUCCESS.asdsadasda

KK.EVENT.CLIENT.00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000.SUCCESS.account-console.LOGIN

KK.EVENT.CLIENT.00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000.SUCCESS.account-console.REGISTER

KK.EVENT

KK.EVENT.asdkjhasjdhaskhdsa
```

I want it to ONLY work for the REGISTER event. I could add an if statement and catch the routing key but I'd really rather just have the routing key sort that for me. Does anyone have any insight into why this is happening? Cheers

Comment: I believe it may have been the fact that during development, your various routing keys that you define persist in RabbitMQ. In the Management plugin I found I saw a KK.# routing key binding that I used, which was making absolutely everything match, though I'm not 100% sure this is my issue.